# Undefined behavior in a C++/CLI wrapper project

Tags: c++

I created a C++/CLI wrapper project whose DLL is being used in another C++ project. While building, there is no error but when I used the wrapper project in the main project one of the functions of the wrapper project is not working correctly.

for example, consider the function written below -

```
int open_device_mac_addr_native (void *param)
    {
        device ^ wrapper = DeviceLibWrapper::instance->device_obj;
        String ^ mac_new = gcnew String ((char *)param);  
        return wrapper->open_device (mac_new);
    }
```

When I try to run the main program (which is calling the function mentioned above), I get "Windows Error 0xe0434352". When I insert a `return 1` as the first line in the function, like below -

```
int open_device_mac_addr_native (void *param)
    {
        return 1;
        device ^ wrapper = DeviceLibWrapper::instance->device_obj;
        String ^ mac_new = gcnew String ((char *)param);  
        return wrapper->open_device (mac_new);
    }
```

It still tries to execute the entire function and I get the same error "Windows Error 0xe0434352". However, when I comment the whole part in the function except the first `return 1`, then the function returns fine.

This is completely baffling behavior to me. It would be really appreciable if someone could share some insights into the root cause of this problem, and guide me towards possible resolutions. Also, I would like to understand why the function doesn't return at the first `return 1`, and tries to execute the entire body despite `return 1` being the first instruction.

With a gesture of gratitude.

Sarthak Malik.

Comment: I've removed your references to Visual Studio 2019 because this isn't a question about using the Visual Studio application. If you intended to tag a specific version of .NET, please do this instead as it tells us more than telling us what IDE you're using.

Comment: This may be an issue of out-of-date dependencies. If you put the `return 1` then the rest of the function should not be executed. I guess that your other project somehow picked up an old version of your DLL (or had that cached somewhere) or you forgot to rebuild your project after making the code change or did not save the code change.
When commenting out you then (implicitly) rebuilt and updated the dependeccy so that the modified code took effect.

Comment: 0xe0434352 tells you that the C++/CLI code threw an unhandled exception.  That is nothing unusual, managed code likes throwing exceptions when something goes wrong.   You just don't know what went wrong, there is no friendly backstop in native code that reports the exception details.  A managed unit test is highly advisable.  Or use the debugger in the native project: Project > Properties > Debugging > "Debugger Type" = Mixed and Debug > Windows > Exception Settings > tick CLR Exceptions.